# CentOS / http2 / ALPN

Tags: apache-httpd, openssl

Now that CentOS 7.4 CR has delivered OpenSSL 1.0.2, I should be able to serve
http/2 pages to Chrome, but I still see messages that ALPN is not enabled.

OpenSSL 1.0.2 is installed:

```
$ rpm -qa |grep openssl
openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64
openssl-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64
```

But https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test says "www.stevenstern.me"
supports http 2 but ALPN is not supported.

Ideas?  Does anything need to be explicitly enabled for ALPN?  As I
mentioned, the http2 stuff seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on how you have installed Apache-Httpd and whether it was compiled against OpenSSL 1.0.2. I would suggest not.

The easiest way to tell is to run `httpd -V` and/or look at the error logs when restarting Apache.

The default build on RHEL7/Centos 7 through yum still installs 2.4.7 which has no http/2 support. So guessing you didn’t use that?

Any other official repo that I’m aware of (e.g. Redhat Software Collections) still build against OpenSSL 1.0.1 so doesn’t give you ALPN - even on 7.4 when it could!

Currently the only options on RHEL7/Centos 7 (even 7.4) are to install from source or from a third party repo like [CodeIT](https://codeit.guru/en_US/) - neither of which are options that a lot of people want to do.